# Sorting CMS Pages

Tags: sorting, vbscript, asp-classic, content-management-system

I have been developing a CMS in ASP VBScript and am now trying to add page sorting capability so admins can order their pages in any way they like.

I have tried adding a *sort_id* column to the database, but since there are many different levels of pages, it is throwing me off. I have also tried using a *slug* column (ie. parent_id/id/id/id) to determine levels and parent id's, but could not get that to work.

I need to be able to sort each parent id, and the child pages within them and print them out on the page according to this order.

I am looking for a push in the right direction because I have been struggling with this one for a while now...

I am using Microsoft Access for DB and currently have the columns:

```
id, page_parent, page_name, page_content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a table in an Access (2010) database that does pretty much what you want. The concept was that I needed to be able to store lookup lists which could have attributes attached to them. The way it worked was a parent id (FK) would point to a record elsewhere in the table (to the PK). An extra couple of fields provided node management via a *node list* in the form **.1.2.34.*n*.** and a *node level* to record the level in the tree of the current node (though this could be skipped by working out how many dots there are in the list, dot count - 1).  The *node list* would record all steps back up the tree to the ultimate ancestor.

[image]

By adding the following **Before Update** data macro the whole process was automated...

[image]

Sorting can be performed then by adding a *sort* field (numeric or whatever) to the end.  Any queries can be told to sort primarily on the *sort* field, and then alphabetically on (in my case) the *code* field.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using SQL Server you could use recursive queries to return a tree like structure but this is not supported in Access.

You may have to add your own column which you would compute yourself whenever the tree structure was changed.

I would add a column (numeric) for the display order and then allow this to be set at each level (parent and child).

I would then create and populate a second column (varchar/string) which stores the computed position in the tree structure. This would consist of each parent's display order value and this item's display order.

To order by this column you would need the display order numbers to have a fixed length.

An example of the computed value for this column is (maximum length of display order 5 digits in this example):

```
00001/00010/00003
```

This example item is in third position of it's parent, which is in tenth position of it's parent, which is in first position at the top level.

You can use whatever separator you want or no separator if you prefer.

Then you can change your SQL order by clause to use this computed column.